# SQL Server: What data type to set for Python/Pandas "bool" data type?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have column that I am trying to insert into a SQL Server table. Python/Pandas rightly detects that it is a Boolean column and assigns it a data type: `bool`.

A sample of its first 20 values are:

```
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False, False])
dtype('bool')
```

If I assign this Pandas column to the SQL the `BIT` data type, I get insert errors:

`(type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage)`

What is the right datatype for this type of column?

Comment: The "closest" data type SQL Server has to a `bool` is `bit`, which can store `1`, `0`, or `NULL` (when `NULL`able).

Comment: Could you create a function or use a case statement to convert to bit? You're almost certainly going to want to store in SQL Server as bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without knowing how you are actually trying to insert the data in your DB. For example, are you using an ODBC Python connector (pyodbc) ?

Anyway with the limited information available, you could try transforming your bool into integer: False -> 0, True -> 1.

Depending on the connector used, it might not support or properly map a Python bool to a SQL Server BIT. But most SQL Servers connectors would be ok mapping int to BIT as long as as the values are 0 or 1 (and NULL if your target column is nullable)